# OverflowError: Unsupported value

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have this function on my project:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.id_document_type == 'BC':
        now = date.today()
        if (now - self.date_of_birth).days < (18 * 365):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid input')
```

However when I fast test it on the terminal I get this error

```
OverflowError: Unsupported value: datetime.datetime(2200, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone>). You should install pytz.
```

yet I already have the latest pytz version. Anyone have an idea of what could be wrong.

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#timedelta-objects) object inorder to subtract days from a date

For example,

```
    from datetime import date, timedelta

    d=date.today()-timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)
```